# Service Broker message stuck, are there any alternative solutions that don't involve reassigning a new broker?

Tags: sql-server, service-broker

Good afternoon,

I have a production service broker queue which stopped processing messages about a month ago. After clearing out the messages that had backed up there remains 8 messages that will not leave the queue. I assume it is these messages that are blocking me from disabling or deleting the queue which would hopefully allow the whole system to start up again.

If I select from the queue I see the 8 messages and they all have a message_type_name of "http://schemas.microsoft.com/SQL/ServiceBroker/EndDialog".

If I match these messages up with sys.conversation_endpoints I get a state_desc of "DISCONNECTED_INBOUND"

Using ssbdiagnose on a specific conversation handle I receive the following error:
Service broker received an END CONVERSATION message on this conversation. Service Broker will not transmit the message; it will be held until the application ends the conversation.

If I try to end the conversation using:

END CONVERSATION ... WITH CLEANUP;

The query just spins, (currently over 20 min).

I get the impression that my next course of action is the following command:

ALTER DATABASE ... SET NEW_BROKER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE;

Not a fan of this after reading some of the fallout but if that is the only option then we'll have to deal with it.

So, thoughts on next steps / any other option than the new broker? If additional information is necessary just let me know.

Thanks!

Comment: Out of curiosity, what does sys.dm_exec_requests say about the SPID on which you issued the end conversation? Is it blocked (or _blocking_)? Is it doing IO/CPU work?

Comment: Ah ha! Yes there was a child query of an update that was stuck running for the past month. I killed it and the parent process wrapped up and now new messages are flowing. The child was set as suspended with a wait type of CXPACKET. It had done a few reads but no writes. I'll review that wait type more thoroughly and next time this occurs will review this table first so we can track down where it is running off the rails. Thank you!

Comment: Ah... glad it ended up being simple! Pulling back the covers, I thought the answer to my questions were going to be "not blocked/blocking" and "doing work" (respectively) to which I was going to respond "let it ride". File this one away in "just another step to add to your troubleshooting process".